# customize the popover in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, popover, angular-ui-bootstrap

In the pop over i want to display some text boxes and buttons into it. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/2gqXoI7Gc7MtT8Ac264R?p=preview
in this link the popover comes with the text "My content" instead of this want to display html elements.

Comment: Check out this Gist: https://gist.github.com/jbruni/6629714

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your `popover` attribute with

```
popover="{{ content }}"
```

and your example.js like so:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('PopoverCtrl', function PopoverCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.content = "test";
  });
```

This is very basic angularjs stuff though, I think you need to do some docs reading.

Comment: please consider accepting the answer if it resolved your original problem.

Comment: how can i bring input box into the popover

Comment: that's a different and unrelated question.

Comment: what is unrelated one i mentioned that in my question

Comment: You need to look into [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml), and if you want to bind models you're probably going to have to `$compile`. But there's too much reading you need to do first.